# Keras UNet: AttributeError

Tags: python, keras, pycharm

I am currently trying to run a U-Net model in Keras, using PyCharm and Anaconda on Windows. My first attempts kept on working well. However, now I'm getting an error when I try to acces keras:

My imports:

```
from unet_model import multi_unet_model 

from keras.utils import normalize
import os
import glob
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
```

The error:
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.client.pywrap_tf_session' has no attribute '**cxx_version**'

Maybe one of you encountered the same problem and can give me a hint how to solve it.

The problem occured after trying to move the model from cpu to gpu. Now the model can't be processed at all. Maybe I changed some references without knowing it.

Comment: What is the tensorflow version you have?

Comment: I am using version 2.11.0